# How can I scrape a certain Item from Homepage in Java including jsoup

Tags: java, web-scraping, jsoup

below I have the code to scrape a yelp page. I need only the site Url from the console. So only in this example the url 'cube-rieger.de' (after noopener nofollow)

```
<a href="/biz_redir?url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.cube-rieger.de&amp;website_link_type=website&amp;src_bizid=q_PKB5C34yMiQ8JfvN2gkg&amp;cachebuster=1573659980&amp;s=80a10c01ecab48c960a0145decb9e8f8c7502d7f239f5a799568cfe9ec1748bd" target="_blank" rel="noopener nofollow">cube-rieger.de</a>
```

Here ist my code for the scraping:

```
package methoden;

import java.io.IOException;

import org.jsoup.*;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;

public class JsoupRun {

        public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

            String url = "https://www.yelp.com/biz/zahn%C3%A4rzte-dr-g-cube-dr-r-cube-"
                    + "und-dr-d-rieger-stuttgart?adjust_creative=LkD6tqXBfUmRYWw5Kapg"
                    + "6Q&utm_campaign=yelp_api_v3&utm_medium=api_v3_business_search&"
                    + "utm_source=LkD6tqXBfUmRYWw5Kapg6Q";

            Document document = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
            Elements links = document.select("noopener nofollow");

            for (Element link : links) {

                System.out.println("link : " + link.attr("href"));
                System.out.println("text : " + link.text());
            }
        }
    }
```

Can someone solve me this problem please?

Answer (score 0):

i guess you are looking for `Element.text()` as explained on the [Api page](https://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/nodes/Element.html). That should return

> cube-rieger.de

Comment: so you mean replace noopener nofollow with Element.text()?

Comment: if you are interested in the text value of the element you should call `link.text();` to get the corresponding text

Comment: Could you please provide me an example? I tried really everything.